# Java Locale object scope is thread or application?

Tags: java, multithreading, locale

I'm writing a multi-threaded Java application in which every user request creates a new thread that should use a different Locale depending on user preferences. This is not a web application so the concept of session does not apply here.

Is there any way to set the default Locale -the active one- just in the thread scope? I have been looking  about it in the documentation and it does not clarify if the default Locale applies to the thread, the class loader, the process or the whole JVM.

Thanks. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

From the Javadoc for `Locale.getDefault`:

> Gets the current value of the default
>   locale for this instance of the Java
>   Virtual Machine.

The default locale is definitely a JVM-wide variable and shouldn't be used to try keep track of the user's locale. You should take a look at [Java Internationalization](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/intl/) that discusses how to go about using these classes.

In your case it seems like you can use a `ThreadLocal<Locale>`, see [ThreadLocal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

Answer (score 0):

On a smaller point, you mention that every user request creates a new thread.. you may want to look into using a threadpool and reusing threads as endless thread creation and destruction will hurt performance. Depending on your usage, you may also want to put a bound on this threadpool to prevent a large number of users grinding your application to a halt

Comment: Yep. The thing is that the application is running on a third party server that is not a servlet container but a proprietary socket server for gaming purposes. This server uses thread pooling to create and destroy threads :)